# Glossaries package: small caps in body and normal caps in the acronym list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, small-caps

I want a list of acronyms to be printed in normal caps. However, I want small caps acronyms in the body text. I use `glossaries` package as the following example. Would you please help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[style=long, toc, smallcaps]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}
\begin{document}
This is an \gls{acr}. An \gls{acr} should be in small caps.
The first column in the follwoing list of acronyms should be in normal caps.
\printglossary[title={List of Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 123 of the [glossaries' user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) reads:

> `\glossaryentryfield{<label>}{<formatted
>   name>}{<desc>}{<symbol>}{<number list>}`
>
> This macro indicates what to do for a given glossary entry. Note that `<formatted
>   name>` will always be in the form `\glsnamefont{<name>}`. This allows
>   the user to set a given font for the entry name, **regardless** of the
>   glossary style used.

With this in mind, one solution to your problem is to change the definition of `\glsnamefont`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[style=long,smallcaps]{glossaries}

\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\immediate\write18{makeglossaries \jobname} % run (pdf)latex twice with --shell-escape
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{acr}; \gls{acr}.
\printglossary[title={List of Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Change the meaning of `\acronymfont` when you want to typeset the list (but I don't think it's a good idea).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[style=long, toc, smallcaps]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}

\begin{document}

This is an \gls{acr}. An \gls{acr} should be in small caps.
The first column in the following list of acronyms should be in normal caps.

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax % this line is just not to have a page break
\renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\printglossary[title={List of Acronyms}]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]